# machine learning in GATE tool

Tags: machine-learning, svm, gate

After running the Machine Learner Algorithm (SVM) on training data using GATE tool, I would like to test it on testing data. My question is, should I use the same trained data to be tested, also, how could the model extract the entities from the test data while the test data not annotated with the annotations that have been learnt in the trained data.

I followed the tutorial on this link http://gate.ac.uk/sale/talks/gate-course-may11/track-3/module-11-machine-learning/module-11.pdf but at the end it was a bit confusing when it talks about splitting the dataset into training and testing.

Answer (score 0):

In GATE you have 3 modes of the machine learning PR - for training, evaluation and application.

What happens when you train is that the ML PR is checking the selected annotation (let's say Token), collecting it's features and learning the target class (i.e. Person, Mention or whatever). Using the example docs, the ML PR creates a model which holds values for features and basically "learns" how to classify new Tokens (or sentences, or other).

When testing, you provide the ML PR only the Tokens with all their features. Then the ML PR uses them as input for its model and decides if or what Mention to create. The ML PR actually needs everything that was there in the training corpus, except the label / target class / mention - the decision that should be made.

I think the GATE ML PR ignores the labels when in test mode, so it's not crucial to remove it.

Evaluation is a helpful option, where training and testing are done automatically, the corpus is split and results are presented. What it does is split the corpus in 2, train on one part, apply the model on the other, compare the gold standard to what it labeled. Repeat with different splits.

The usual sequence is to train and evaluate, check results, fix, add features, etc. and when you're happy with the evaluation results, switch to application and run on data that doesn't have labels.

It is crucial that you run the same pre-processing when you're training and testing. For instance if in training you've run a POS tagger and you skip this when testing, the ML PR won't have the "Token.category" feature and will calculate very different results.

Now to your questions :)

NO! Don't use the same data for testing, that is a very common mistake, if you get suspiciously good results, first check if you're doing that.

In the tutorial, when you split the corpus both parts will have all the annotations as before, so the ML PR will have all the features it needed. In real life, you'll have to run some pre-processing first as docs will come without tokens or anything.

Splitting in their case is done very simple - just save all docs to files, split files in two folders, load them as two corpora.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It was very helpful, but the problem that I'm facing is when I run the ML PR on the training data, and the training data has all the annotations/labels, the ML PR gives good indication that my training data has all what it needs for learning the model. Once I run the application mode on my testing data ( data that has no annotations/labels, it is raw data), i could not see any results as I saw when I run the whole data set (training+testing data) in the evaluation mode.
Is it technical problem in Gate? I would like to see the results when I run the application mode on the testing data.

Comment: Please, help to get me out of this problem

Comment: Ok, the problem is not in GATE. It's not easy to guess what's wrong but I think that when you run on a new document, you didn't run ANNIE before running the ML PR. I said that 3 times in my reply... First run ANNIE, generate Tokens and everything, then run the ML PR - you need the whole preprocessing you did when training/testing.

Comment: Okay, I got it, I'll try to run ANNIE before to run ML PR on testing data